# Select different and visible colors automatically for ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot a series of geom_points on my box plot and I want to automatically select good, different, visible colors for them. I am trying to assign themmanually here and they are not printing at all:

Sample random rows of the data:

```
> dput(Moment_UG.84[sample(nrow(Moment_UG.84), 20), ])
structure(list(UG = c(84, 84, 84, 84, 84, 84, 84, 84, 84, 84, 
84, 84, 84, 84, 84, 84, 84, 84, 84, 84), S = c(9, 15, 12, 15, 
12, 15, 9, 12, 9, 9, 15, 15, 12, 15, 12, 12, 15, 12, 15, 15), 
N_l = c(3, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 1, 3, 3, 
3, 3, 1), Sample = c(NA, "Sample", NA, "Sample", "Sample", 
"Sample", NA, "Sample", NA, NA, "Sample", "Sample", "Sample", 
NA, "Sample", "Sample", NA, "Sample", NA, "Sample"), EQ = c("Henry", 
"CSI", "AASHTO", "CSI", "CSI", "CSI", "Phuvor", "CSI", "Phuvor", 
"Suks", "CSI", "CSI", "CSI", "Phuvor", "CSI", "CSI", "Tarhini", 
"CSI", "Suks", "CSI"), DF = c(0.771054545454546, 0.6212923327743, 
0.820459380622491, 0.969232941454771, 0.81407904739181, 0.836289660367203, 
1.36687279880613, 0.671549498773624, 1.36687279880613, 0.470526198172626, 
0.965515794715837, 0.425884565484171, 0.569005483833933, 
1.97077029619609, 0.584398599194936, 0.835948975252443, 3.23270918275927, 
0.777877727743711, 0.954915937321423, 0.638980947084365), 
Girder = c("Interior", "Exterior", "Interior", "Exterior", 
"Exterior", "Interior", "Interior", "Interior", "Interior", 
"Exterior", "Exterior", "Interior", "Exterior", "Exterior", 
"Exterior", "Exterior", "Exterior", "Exterior", "Interior", 
"Exterior"), Loading = c("Multi", "Single", "Multi", "Multi", 
"Multi", "Multi", "Single", "Multi", "Multi", "Single", "Multi", 
"Single", "Single", "Multi", "Single", "Multi", "Multi", 
"Multi", "Multi", "Single"), X = c("Interior Girder Multi-lane", 
"Exterior Girder Single-lane", "Interior Girder Multi-lane", 
"Exterior Girder Multi-lane", "Exterior Girder Multi-lane", 
"Interior Girder Multi-lane", "Interior Girder Single-lane", 
"Interior Girder Multi-lane", "Interior Girder Multi-lane", 
"Exterior Girder Single-lane", "Exterior Girder Multi-lane", 
"Interior Girder Single-lane", "Exterior Girder Single-lane", 
"Exterior Girder Multi-lane", "Exterior Girder Single-lane", 
"Exterior Girder Multi-lane", "Exterior Girder Multi-lane", 
"Exterior Girder Multi-lane", "Interior Girder Multi-lane", 
"Exterior Girder Single-lane")), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Attempt to plot the data by selecting a subset of the data to go to the geom_boxplots and the remaining as separate geom_points with different colors:

```
ggplot(data = subset(Moment_UG.84, EQ == "CSI"), 
   aes(x = X, y = DF, fill = factor(S,levels = c("9","12","15")))) + 
    geom_boxplot(outlier.shape = NA, position = position_dodge(width = 0.75)) +
    stat_summary(fun = mean, geom="point", shape=23, size=2, 
             position = position_dodge(width = 0.75)) + 
    stat_boxplot(geom='errorbar', linetype=1, width=0.5,
             position = position_dodge(width = 0.75)) +
    geom_point(data = subset(Moment_UG.84, EQ == "AASHTO"), 
           aes(colour = Sample), position = position_dodge(width = 0.75)) +
    geom_point(data = subset(Moment_UG.84, EQ == "Henry"), 
           aes(colour = Sample), position = position_dodge(width = 0.75)) +
    geom_point(data = subset(Moment_UG.84, EQ == "Phuvor"), 
           aes(colour = Sample), position = position_dodge(width = 0.75)) +
    geom_point(data = subset(Moment_UG.84, EQ == "Suks"), 
           aes(colour = Sample), position = position_dodge(width = 0.75)) +
    geom_point(data = subset(Moment_UG.84, EQ == "Tarhini"), 
           aes(colour = Sample), position = position_dodge(width = 0.75)) +
    geom_point(data = subset(Moment_UG.84, EQ == "Shahawy"), 
           aes(colour = Sample), position = position_dodge(width = 0.75)) +
    geom_point(data = subset(Moment_UG.84, EQ == "Rigid"), 
           aes(colour = Sample), position = position_dodge(width = 0.75)) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("AASHTO" = "red1", "Henry" = "cyan3", 
                            "Phuvor" = "dodgerblue", "Suks" = "green1",
                            "Tarhini" = "darkviolet", "Shahawy" = "deeppink2",
                            "Rigid" = "orangered1")) +
  labs(x = element_blank(), y = element_blank(), 
     title = paste0("Moment Live Load Distribution Factors \n Ultra-Girder Section: UG-84"),
     fill = "Girder Spacing (ft):", colour = element_blank()) +
theme_classic() + theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, margin = margin(45,0,20,0), 
                                face = "bold", size = 18), 
      legend.title.align = 0.5, legend.position = "bottom", 
      legend.box.background = element_rect(colour = "black", size = 0.5),
      legend.box.margin = margin(0,0,0,0))
```

It seems like it is not printing the geom_points at all even though i get no errors

Comment: Unfortunately I can't quite understand what you want. `Sample` column contains only `"Sample"` and `NA`. What does it mean you want to color according to `Sample` if it contains only one value (and `NA`)? Do you want one color for `Sample` and one for NA?

Comment: why can't you call boxplot() on the subset and geom_point() on the full dataset with col = EQ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already suggested by @StupidWolf in his comment, you main issue is that you mapped `Sample` on `color` instead of `EQ`. And there is no need for separate `geom_point` layers. One `geom_point` is sufficient:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data = subset(Moment_UG.84, EQ == "CSI"), 
       aes(x = X, y = DF, fill = factor(S,levels = c("9","12","15")))) + 
  geom_boxplot(outlier.shape = NA, position = position_dodge(width = 0.75)) +
  stat_summary(fun = mean, geom="point", shape=23, size=2, 
               position = position_dodge(width = 0.75)) + 
  stat_boxplot(geom='errorbar', linetype=1, width=0.5,
               position = position_dodge(width = 0.75)) +
  geom_point(data = subset(Moment_UG.84, EQ != "CSI"), aes(colour = EQ), position = position_dodge(width = 0.75)) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("AASHTO" = "red1", "Henry" = "cyan3", 
                                "Phuvor" = "dodgerblue", "Suks" = "green1",
                                "Tarhini" = "darkviolet", "Shahawy" = "deeppink2",
                                "Rigid" = "orangered1")) +
  labs(x = element_blank(), y = element_blank(), 
       title = paste0("Moment Live Load Distribution Factors \n Ultra-Girder Section: UG-84"),
       fill = "Girder Spacing (ft):", colour = element_blank()) +
  theme_classic() + theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, margin = margin(45,0,20,0), 
                                                    face = "bold", size = 18), 
                          legend.title.align = 0.5, legend.position = "bottom", 
                          legend.box.background = element_rect(colour = "black", size = 0.5),
                          legend.box.margin = margin(0,0,0,0))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you now is there a way to not define the colors myself and have the program automatically select good, visible colors for me?

Comment: Hi Maral. Hm. Choosing colors is not easy. But if you want good colors set automatically then try with one of the brewer palettes,  e.g. try `scale_color_brewer(type = "qual", palette = "Accent")` for categorical data as in your case. See e.g. https://www.r-graph-gallery.com/38-rcolorbrewers-palettes.html for an overview of the brewer pals.